# Issue with Powermockito verifystatic

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a legacy class which has a static void method which i need to test:

```
public class A {

    public static void renameTo()
    {
        String ext = "." + this.fileName + ".backup";
        for (File file : getCSVFile()) {
            f.renameTo(new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ext));
        }

    public static File[] getAllFiles()
    {
        //logic to read the CSV files from the class path
    }


}
```

Now I have written a test case for it using PowerMockito which looks like this. Now the issue is,  even though the `renameTo()` is called only, if i call `PowerMockito.verifyStatic( Mockito.times(10))` the test still passes

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void testRenameTo() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
        A.renameTo();
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic( Mockito.times(1));
        //PowerMockito.verifyStatic( Mockito.times(5));//Passes even though the mehod is called only once    
        //PowerMockito.verifyStatic( Mockito.times(10);//Passes even though the mehod is called only once    
    } 
}
```

Could someone please shed some light into this issue? what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-verify-exact-number-of-calls), after the test `verifyStatic` needs to be called first, then call `A.renameTo()` to tell it which static method to verify. Example:

```
// run test
A.renameTo();

// verify interaction
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(A.class, Mockito.times(1));
A.renameTo();
```

Comment: Hi Chris, If I do that I get this exception :                                         
`Wanted but not invoked com.legacy.app.test.A.renameTo();
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
 at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl.performIntercept(MockitoMethodInvocationControl.java:262)
 at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl.invoke(MockitoMethodInvocationControl.java:190)`

Comment: The exception indicates that Powermock did not record any calls to `A.renameTo()`. Can you post your reworked code?

Comment: I just put the call to `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(5))` before callling `renameTo()`
        `PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(5));
        A.renameTo();`

Comment: But if i run it like this as shown below it does call the renameTo method but the verifyStatic still accepts any value for the Mockito.times() and test pases
    `@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Test
    public void testGetCsvFiles() throws Exception {
 { 
  A spy = PowerMockito.spy(new A());
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1));
        spy.renameTo(();
   
 }`

Comment: Sorry, I realized I worded my original answer poorly. Edited to be clearer + example.

Comment: Hi Chris , thanks for pointer . I did what you have suggested but it still takes in any value for Mockito.time(4)  `@Test
    public void testRenameTo() throws Exception {
        A spy = PowerMockito.spy(new A());
        spy.renameTo(();
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(A.class,Mockito.times(1));
        spy.renameTo(();
        
    }` and passes the test instead of checking for times(1)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how `verifyStatic` interacts with partial mocking (`spy()`). The documentation doesn't say much about it, they only show examples of verifying instance methods of a partial mock. As an aside, it's generally a bad convention to call a static method on an instance of an Object.